# Loading same util,js twice

Tags: javascript

I have a main html page that uses 2 libraries by including them like this

```
<script src="js/lib1.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib2.js"></script>
```

but both of them uses a utility library util.js

inside both lib1 and lib2 I load util.js dynamically, like this

```
fileref=document.createElement('script');
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src", "js/util.js");
fileref.onload = util_is_loaded;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

with the onload function doing something like this

```
function util_is_loaded(){
    myutil = new util();
}
```

And it all works honky dorey - but, I know that I am loading the same util.js twice - this is my problem.

I tried to determine, if the util.js was already loaded before calling createElement, and only create the element if it was not loaded, my code looked a bit like this;

```
util_is_loaded = false;
heads = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
for (hd=0;hd <heads.length;hd++){
    scripts = heads[hd].getElementsByTagName("script");
    for (sc=0; sc < scripts.length;sc++){
        if (scripts[sc].hasAttribute("src")){
            source = scripts[sc].getAttribute("src");
            n = source.lastIndexOf("/");
            if (n > 0){
                if (source.substr(n+1).toLowerCase() == "util.js"){
                    util_is_loaded = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and that atually is able to determine if the util.js is present in the head section.

However, while lib1 is currently working on loading util.js, lib2 is determining it is already present and call

```
new util();
```

Which fails as it is not yet there....

My questions are many, but they are all centered around the original question; how to avoid loading script multiple times when loading them dynamically....

Answer (score 0):

If `lib1` & `lib2` are always required, you can load `util` outside of them, I mean before like below:

```
<script src="js/util.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib1.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib2.js"></script>
```

Otherwise you can declare util variable before you load libs and use it inside both lib1 & lib2

```
<script> var util; </script>
<script src="js/lib1.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib2.js"></script>
```

and inside lib1 & lib2:

```
if(!util) {
    fileref=document.createElement('script');
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    fileref.setAttribute("src", "js/util.js");
    fileref.onload = util_is_loaded;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileref);
    util = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amadou,

I did consider both solutions, but discarded them in the jhope for something better :-)

ad 1, I do not like author of main.html to need to know, that the 2 libs are using util.js - he should only consider, that he needs lib1.js and lib2.js. Other than that, this works 100%.

ad2. this also leaves me hanging a bit, as I want to allocate the utility to make it ready for the libs to use. When will util.js be ready to use? lib1.js can use the onload callback, but how will lib2.js know the script is loaded and he is ready to allocate his own util object?

Comment: @Raketten1963 My answer is based on your code snippet. If you want to load script properly then I recommand you to use Webpack or any module bundler. In the second example, the first lib loaded will load the util file and call your `util_is_loaded` which is gonna instanciate the myutil variable

Comment: Keep in mind default variables are `var` type and it is function scope. So if you don't declare `myutil` outside of `util_is_loaded`, it won't be accessible